# error typeerror _co.onclick is not a function - Angular 2

Tags: angular

I get ERROR TypeError: _co.onClick is not a function error with angular 2.

```
<span
    class="glyphicon"
    [class.glyphicon-star]="isFavorite"
    [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!isFavorite"
    (click)="onClick()">
</span>
```

When user click the star that it should be color or empty. then my component ts file is here

```
@Component({
  selector: 'favorite',
  templateUrl: './favorite.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./favorite.component.css']
})
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare that *onClick* function in your component.

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'favorite',
      templateUrl: './favorite.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./favorite.component.css']
    })

    export class FavoriteComponent {

      constructor() { }

      onClick() {
        console.log("star clicked");
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem even after declaring the function in my component.So I changed the function name and it worked.